# Fingering for Bach piano sinfonia n.1 BWV787

Tags: piano, fingering

Second measure of Bach piano sinfonia N.1 BWV787.

[image: Bach piano sinfonia N.1 BWV787]

What's the usual piano fingering for the highlighted excerpt? If I'm not wrong you tend to avoid pedal on Bach pieces and C-E' interval is pretty large.

Comment: Well, nothing will be slurred by the pedal until you play the 16th-note D.  So for smoothness, I'd play both middle C notes under a pedal, play the 2nd middle C with the 4th finger and hold it.

Comment: As a general point, you should ignore the division between staves.  Ideally, you should think of a Bach sinfonia as being written for 3 independent hands on 3 staves, but of course you only have two hands so you have to make it sound 3 handed as well as you can, and that includes dividing the notes to be played by your middle hand between your left and right hands in whatever way best furthers that illusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from this [performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDsF54ppP_o) one way you can do this is to bring your left hand over to do the first 4 notes of the scale. The first C would be 1 and then immediately hit C again with 5. [image: notation with fingering]

Comment: I think 4 would be better, because the F is on the beat.